# Set a Parsed (JSON) image into background of a layout?

Tags: android, bitmap, hyperlink

I have got a demo image link :

`http://madhabpurps.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/04/28-239x300.jpg`

I want to set the image in the background of a layout inside the view holder class:

```
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtCityState;
    RelativeLayout rl;
}

holder.txtName.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getTitle());
holder.txtCityState.setText(searchArrayList.get(position).getDescription());
```

I have to set the image from the link here, I have tried this line of code but it's showing error.

```
holder.rl.setBackgroundResource(searchArrayList.get(position).getImage());
```

Comment: you have to download it first

Comment: Can you provide me the line of code to download the image ?

Comment: Look for Android HttpClient

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get answer from here [change background image of Framelayout via URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586097/change-background-image-of-framelayout-via-url)

```
private Drawable ImageOperations(Context ctx, String url, String saveFilename) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) this.fetch(url);
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, saveFilename);
            return d;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }
```

and then you can use it like this

```
Drawable drw = ImageOperations(this,url,filename)
rl.setBackgroundDrawable(drw);
```

This should fix. But for general case I recommend another way to solve these problems.

I recommend using a well documented image downloading and caching library. I am using picasso http://square.github.io/picasso/ . Setup it, using library is easy.

Then you can fill an imageview by just writing

```
Picasso.with(activity)
 .load(url)
 .fit()
 .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Picasso.with(this)
    .load(searchArrayList.get(position).getDescription())
    .resize(50, 50)          
    .centerCrop()
    .into(holder.rl);

Comment: 1st parameter is getting error

Comment: I just write it for sample purpose, first parameter is context, or in your case your current activity. FYI: picasso sample app codes are here https://github.com/square/picasso/tree/master/picasso-sample

Comment: This link is superb..just add the jar file into project and parse any kind of web link with compression and perfection    http://square.github.io/picasso/ .....Thanx to Yekmer Simsek for this link

Answer (score 0):

use the below code

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bitmap);
rl.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);
```

Comment: Can you provide details about getResources() ???

Comment: And what will be in `enter code here` ?? should it be "d"

Comment: getResources() Return a Resources instance for your application's package. if u r not in activity use Context.getResources() and u should know that after android 3Ice cream sandwish u should use separate thread to call http url

Comment: Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream)new URL(url).getContent());
  Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(Context.getResources(),bitmap);
  holder.rl.setBackgroundDrawable(dr);